# SQL query returns necessary data, but the procedure doesn't

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to create a procedure that returns the list of entries from two tables. Here's the code for the procedure:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE goods_to_transfer
    IS
     begin
        for rec in (select sales.good_id, sales.good_count, goods.priority 
                    FROM goods,sales 
                    where sales.good_id=goods.id and sales.delivered='YES');
 
    loop
        
    dbms_output.put_line( 'GOOD ID' || rec.good_id);
    dbms_output.put_line( 'GOOD COUNT' || rec.good_count);
    dbms_output.put_line( 'PRIORITY' || rec.good_priority);

   end loop;
     end goods_to_transfer;
```

The execution ends up with the following mistakes:

> ORA-01403: no data found
> ORA-06512: in  "C##XSENIA.GOODS_TO_TRANSFER", line 7
> ORA-06512: in  line 2

The same query returns all the necessary data:

```
select sales.good_id, sales.good_count, goods.priority FROM goods,sales 
        where sales.good_id=goods.id and sales.delivered='YES'
```

I wonder if anyone could possibly tell me, what do I do wrong.
Thank you!

Comment: Code you posted is a) invalid, b) can't **ever** return ORA-01403, so - if you want to get useful answer, post useful question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to remove the ; at the end of the request

```
for rec in (select sales.good_id, sales.good_count, goods.priority 
                    FROM goods,sales 
                    where sales.good_id=goods.id and sales.delivered='YES')
```